# Override operators with a left and right parameter

Tags: c++

I have the simple setup:

```
#include<iostream>

class Stuff {};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &lhs, const Stuff &rhs) {
    return lhs << "something";
}

int main() {
    Stuff stuff;

    cout << stuff << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

where the `operator<<` function prints the mockup `Stuff` class to an `ostream`. What I would like to do though is move that function into the `Stuff` class itself. As in:

```
class Stuff {
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &lhs, const Stuff &rhs) {
        return lhs << "something";
    }
};
```

For the life of me though, I can't figure out how to get this to work. I get the sense that I'm trying to re-define a left associative operator from the right side. Is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: I think you forgot `friend` in front of that decl in the second snippet. It should be a free function; not a member.

Comment: @WhozCraig please make that as an answer.

Comment: When you do, can you explain why I should use `friend` as opposed to `static`?

Comment: @sircodesalot I'll write something up, no worries (but if someone beats me to it with a reasonable answer by-all-means tag it and get back to your project =P ). EDIT: Jonathan's answer covers this nicely, no need for me to).

Comment: And regarding static, consider what your invoke would have to be like to access that class-static member. (Hint, it would be dreadful). Just make it a friended free-function.

Comment: As a static member you'd have to say `Stuff::operator<<(std::cout, stuff)` for name lookup to find the function (ADL doesn't look for class-scope static functions, only namespace-scope functions) which is ugly as hell, and negates the benefit of overloading operators. Since there is no reason to use such ugliness, the standard doesn't even allow it, see [over.oper]/6 "An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you've defined it, that function would be a member of `Stuff`, so if it was allowed in C++ you'd have to call it like this:

```
Stuff stuff;
stuff.operator<<(std::cout, stuff);
```

So you don't want that.

A binary operator (like `<<`) takes two arguments (called operands). If it's a (non-static) member function then it must be a member function taking one parameter, where the left operand is the object that you call the function on, and the right operand is the function parameter.  So you could do this:

```
struct Stuff {
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o) { return o << something; }
};

Stuff s;
s << std::cout << std::endl;
```

But you probably don't want that either!

To write `std::cout << s` the operator must either be a member of the left operand or must be a non-member function, so you cannot make it a member of `Stuff`.

Maybe what you're trying to do is this:

```
class Stuff {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const Stuff& rhs) {
        return lhs << "something";
    }
};
```

A `friend` function is not a member function, so this is valid.